# How do i override the default behaviour of declineInvitation() method in google games services APIs?

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

For a turn-based multiplayer game, when starting a match if you call declineInvitation()

> The user's participant status changes to STATUS_DECLINED and the match status changes to MATCH_STATUS_CANCELED

I don't want to cancel the match when a player declines, but want the other players to continue with the game. So basically i want to set the status of the match as **MATCH_TURN_STATUS_INVITED** or something similar.

I am using the baseGameUtils library, and going through the sample turn-based game [TbmpSkeleton](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/SkeletonTbmp/src/main/java/com/google/example/tbmpskeleton/SkeletonActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling DismissInvitation() instead of DeclineInvitation().. DismissInvitation would not change status of game for other players.

Look at the below link for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer.html#declineInvitation%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: I get that, but my game demands that on decline i want the other players to continue. And moreover, i would have other places in my code where i need to override the common behaviour and that's why the the more general question on how can i override.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't want to *decline* the invitation, you simply want to *ignore* it. The status is initially **MATCH_TURN_STATUS_INVITED**. If you ignore it, it will remain like that ,which is what you want.

In order to *ignore* the invitation, just don't respond to it.

Otherwise, you can override `onInvitationReceived()` and show your own alert dialog that simply does nothing when the user clicks on *Decline Invitation*.